# CGO: when should C.free() be used?

Tags: cgo

```
func Encode(p SomeStruct) (buf []byte, err error) {
    var bs bytes.Buffer
    if err = json.NewEncoder(&bs).Encode(p); err != nil {
        return
    }
    in := C.CString(bs.String())
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(in))  //Is this necessary?
    res := make([]byte, 1024)
    out := C.CString(string(res))
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(out)) //and this one 
    res := C.encode(in, out, 1024)  //int encode(char *, void *, int)
    //... ...
}
```

Question: shall I use C.free() to ensure that the code does not leak memory? I feel that this is **not** required as the variable is allocated by Go, not C, right?

My question is, will CString **always** allocate memory or, it will do that only if necessary?

```
// Go string to C string
// The C string is allocated in the C heap using malloc.
// It is the caller's responsibility to arrange for it to be
// freed, such as by calling C.free (be sure to include stdlib.h
// if C.free is needed).
func C.CString(string) *C.char
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the documentation, you need release the memory manually. The `CString` function (`_Cfunc_CString` in `cmd/cgo/out.go`) actually calls *malloc* from C standard library and the programmer is supposed to manage this memory. The returned string can be deallocated with `C.free` in the Go side or with `free` inside the C code.